# Graphs of $e^{-y} = x$ and $y = \frac 1x$: Why do they seem so similar on $[0, 1]$, but one converges while the other diverges?

Tags: limits, definite-integrals, graphing-functions, area, divergent-integrals

[image]

First things first, in the above graphs the one in **blue** is just a rotated version of **e<sup>x</sup>** from where the question did really form. I rotated it just in order to make comparisons easier.

If we did the integral of both the functions in **[0,1]** we see that it's value for the **blue** curve is finite(i.e. -0.632) but for the **green** one it is non-existent (of-course as **0** isn't in it's domain).

But again if we repeat the same process in **(0,1]** we find that although the value approaches the one we found before for the **blue** curve, it keeps on increasing (diverging) for the **green** one as closer and closer we get to **0**.

I wish to know why even as both the curves are essentially of the same type in **[0,1]**, one limits it's area to a finite value while the other keeps on diverging.

Comment: They are both smooth on $(0,\infty)$, concave and diverging to $\infty$ at $x=0$, that's about it. You can find lots of functions that do this.

Comment: Why do you think the curves are "essentially the same type".  They look very different to me.

Comment: @fleablood when I say essentially same I mean regarding there slopes and there diverging nature.

Comment: That's just not enough to claim the are "essentially the same".  The slopes increase/decrease at different rates and as you point out one eventually diverges will the other doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are not of the same type: the blue curve is exponential decay. We have
$$
\color{blue}{\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-y}\,dy }= \left.- e^{-y}\right|_{0}^{\infty} = 1 - 0 =1
$$The green curve is a reciprocal function. We have
$$
\color{green}{\int_{0}^{1} x^{-1}dx}= \left.\ln|x|\right|_{0}^{1} = 0 - (-\infty) =\infty
$$

Comment: So should I conclude, areas of diverging functions can be with or without limits depending upon the function?

Comment: Yes; there are broad theorems to deal with classes of functions, but just because a function has a singularity on a domain does not mean its definite integral on that domain doesn't exist.